# Can't update a value in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some data in an sqlite3 database, I made an input to be a command to update that data.
for some reason when I run that command it does not work and gives me an **sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: "some lettres"**

my function to update the data: (the generate_pwd() function works just fine and it has been tested)

```
    def update_query(self, wbname):
        """this function enables the user to update a query

        Args:
            wbname (str): the website name to change the pass
        """
        with conn:
            newpwd = go.generate_pwd()
            c.execute(f"UPDATE password_list SET password={newpwd} WHERE website_name={wbname}")
        pass
```

my elif statement to make the command:

```
elif command == "u":
    wbname = input("Enter the site name: ")
    co.update_query(wbname)
```

> I hope it is clear enough, If you need any further data on my problem just type in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use f-strings with SQL.

Use parametrized queries [as explained in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) instead:

```
c.execute(f"UPDATE password_list SET password=? WHERE website_name=?", (newpwd, wbname))
```

Comment: Waiting for the seven minutes to pass so I can confirm your answer

Comment: JFTR, "You can't use f-strings with SQL" is not quite right. You can do it. But "THOU SHALT NOT FORMAT PARAMETERS YOURSELVES" is true of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap string values in the query within single quotes, otherwise they will be interpreted as column objects:

```
c.execute(f"UPDATE password_list SET password='{newpwd}' WHERE website_name='{wbname}'")
```

You might want to use a parameterized query instead of building a query string. That way your query is less vulnerable to SQL injections.

As parameters you can pass an interable object, e.g. a tuple or a list.

```
c.execute("UPDATE password_list SET password=? WHERE website_name=?", [newpwd, wbname])
```

You could also use named-style parameters:

```
c.execute("UPDATE password_list SET password=:pw WHERE website_name=:wbname", {"pw": newpwd, "wbname": wbname})
```

Another advantage of using parameterized queries is that you do not have to worry about wrapping strings in single quotes.

Comment: Never do this with SQL; it will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Not if you sanitize your inputs. This is nonethelesse a valid answer and it explains why OP gets the ``no such column`` exception. While "You can't use f-strings with SQL." is wrong. The f-string is evaluated before it's passed to the sql engine.

Comment: Obviously the input isn't sanizized and there is no reason to use something other than a parameterized version of the SQL statement here. Of course it's good to explain what was wrong, but the solution should show how it's done. Yes, I can show someone how to use a hammer to put a screw in a screw anchor, but it would be better if I teach them how to use a screwdriver.

Comment: @MikeScotty Sanitization is not the right approach, correct quoting would be. But you can't generally know better how to quote a string than the SQL engine itself can.